# Why does Docker say it can't execute 'bash"?

Tags: docker

I'm using Docker on MacOSX (with Boot2Docker).

I can run images from Docker Hub.

However, when I try to run one of my own images like this:

```
docker run -P mylocalimage
```

or

```
docker run -P mylocalimage bin/a3-write-back
```

or

```
...
```

I get:

```
docker "env: can't execute 'bash': No such file or directory"
```

I guess that it can't find a bash binary to execute in the container, but why?

The base image is `errordeveloper/oracle-jdk`

Thanks for any help.

Ashley.

```
[{
    "Architecture": "amd64",
    "Author": "ABC email@email.com",
    "Checksum": "tarsum.dev+sha256:e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855",
    "Comment": "",
    "Config": {
        "AttachStderr": false,
        "AttachStdin": false,
        "AttachStdout": false,
        "Cmd": [],
        "CpuShares": 0,
        "Cpuset": "",
        "Domainname": "",
        "Entrypoint": [
            "bin/a3-write-back"
        ],
        "Env": [
            "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/jdk1.8.0_25/bin",
            "JAVA_HOME=/usr/jdk1.8.0_25"
        ],
        "ExposedPorts": null,
        "Hostname": "5bf0de3d0926",
        "Image": "abd65ce243a5b015bb49f3e958103a5cc0c5f14938df4e480ded25f3ecf878e7",
        "MacAddress": "",
        "Memory": 0,
        "MemorySwap": 0,
        "NetworkDisabled": false,
        "OnBuild": [],
        "OpenStdin": false,
        "PortSpecs": null,
        "StdinOnce": false,
        "Tty": false,
        "User": "daemon",
        "Volumes": null,
        "WorkingDir": "/opt/docker"
    },
    "Container": "987d2279b6e42195fe8e732c0637798926db6cfaeab93fcc25a3f10dac73f111",
    "ContainerConfig": {
        "AttachStderr": false,
        "AttachStdin": false,
        "AttachStdout": false,
        "Cmd": [
            "/bin/sh",
            "-c",
            "#(nop) CMD []"
        ],
        "CpuShares": 0,
        "Cpuset": "",
        "Domainname": "",
        "Entrypoint": [
            "bin/a3-write-back"
        ],
        "Env": [
            "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/jdk1.8.0_25/bin",
            "JAVA_HOME=/usr/jdk1.8.0_25"
        ],
        "ExposedPorts": null,
        "Hostname": "5bf0de3d0926",
        "Image": "abd65ce243a5b015bb49f3e958103a5cc0c5f14938df4e480ded25f3ecf878e7",
        "MacAddress": "",
        "Memory": 0,
        "MemorySwap": 0,
        "NetworkDisabled": false,
        "OnBuild": [],
        "OpenStdin": false,
        "PortSpecs": null,
        "StdinOnce": false,
        "Tty": false,
        "User": "daemon",
        "Volumes": null,
        "WorkingDir": "/opt/docker"
    },
    "Created": "2015-01-13T05:25:38.467586784Z",
    "DockerVersion": "1.4.1",
    "Id": "ddbd5d3f52cc5fd41605c95e4525cd2f3e0808a3741b3f8d77f46f0661945f7b",
    "Os": "linux",
    "Parent": "abd65ce243a5b015bb49f3e958103a5cc0c5f14938df4e480ded25f3ecf878e7",
    "Size": 0,
    "VirtualSize": 390826666
}
]
```

Comment: Is your entrypoint correct ? I see ` "Entrypoint": [ "bin/a3-write-back" ],` should it be /bin instead of bin ? Can you post your Dockerfile ?

Comment: Yeah, remember your "bash" command will be being interpreted by your entrypoint script, which may well be the issue

Comment: What does bin/a3-write-back look like? If it is a bash script, is it the correct path to the bash script at the top?
Another thing to try is `docker run -P mylocalimage /bin/bash` and see what happens from there, you should have a shell.

Answer (score 162, accepted):

Your image is based on busybox, which doesn't have a bash shell. It does have a shell at `/bin/sh`.

So this doesn't work:

```
$ docker run -it busybox bash
exec: "bash": executable file not found in $PATH2015/01/15 11:09:08 Error response from daemon: 
Cannot start container a5074af2f81f8cc1eb0076f4ec9ada5f87be1440006f54a9b06ab701fc60176a: exec:  
"bash": executable file not found in $PATH
```

But this does:

```
$ docker run -it busybox /bin/sh
/ #
```

There may be further complications due to your entrypoint script, but you can always override that.

Comment: Geezus Christ this took me forever. Thank you. 
Note this only works on CMD for me

Comment: On Windows this will paste the absolute path inside the container where my git-bash.exe is sitting

Comment: In my case, `/bin/sh ` symlinks to `/bin/busybox`, I tried to do this `docker run -it container_name /bin/sh` but it did not work. Could you please explain why?

Comment: @Long I'm not sure. You'd need to open a new question with full information on what you've tried and what the results were

Comment: I was able to do it. But I dont know why, although it goes into bash: `/code #` it freezes when I add a command. No answer after that.

Answer (score 6):

How to override docker run with bash if your image has an ENTRYPOINT defined:

```sh
docker run -it --entrypoint /bin/bash <your-image>
```

Answer (score 2):

This won't work if your image has a defined ENTRYPOINT. For these cases use:
'
docker run -it --entrypoint /bin/bash 
'

Answer (score 0):

If you use sbt-native-packager you just need to add support

```
enablePlugins(AshScriptPlugin)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this and many other common issues by adding this to your `Dockerfile`:

`RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache build-base gcc autoconf automake zlib-dev libpng-dev nasm bash vips-dev git`

Answer (score 0):

This can be because you are using an alpine image and it doesn't have bash by default.

Add the following line into the Dockerfile

```
RUN apk update && apk add bash
```

Reference: https://davidwalsh.name/docker-bash