# Unable to access DOCKER Container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have set up two containers for Nginx and NodeJS in Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial on AWS. I use docker-compose. Everything works fine.

I would like to look into the Nginx container. For the same I use the command:

```
sudo docker exec -it <container-name> bash
```

And I get the following error

```
oci runtime error: exec failed: container_linux.go:265: starting container process caused "exec: \"bash\": executable file not found in $PATH"
```

The path is (using echo $PATH)

/home/ubuntu/bin:/home/ubuntu/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin

The docker-compose.yml is:

```
version: "0.9"
services:

nginx:
  build: ./nginx
  restart: always
  ports:
    - "80:80"
    - "443:443"
  volumes:
    - /etc/letsencrypt/:/etc/letsencrypt/
  links:
    - node:node

node:
  build: ./node
  restart: always
  ports:
   - "8080:8080"
  volumes:
    - ./node:/usr/src/app
    - /usr/src/app/node_modules
```

How do I access the container? Thanks

Comment: I tried using `/bin/bash` still same error

Comment: You should show your Dockerfiles, not just the Compose

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does Docker say it can't execute 'bash"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27959011/why-does-docker-say-it-cant-execute-bash)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you sure that bash interpreter is available in your docker image ? It is not available in base alpine image for example.

You can try starting the container with :

```
sudo docker exec -it <container-name> sh
```

And see if the error still occurs.

BTW, `usermod -aG docker <username>` will allow you not to use sudo anymore to run docker command as user `<username>` .

Comment: @Raj Not all containers actually need Bash shell

Comment: It did work and I am able to access the directories. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> The path is (using echo $PATH)

That's your host machine... Your error indicates you are can't get into the container, so not sure why you echoed that.

We can't see your base images, but the Apline images don't come with bash. You'd have to install it extra. `sh` should work though.

If you're using docker compose to run the containers, you can  use it to exec commands.

And if you only want to list folders, you only need `ls`

```
docker-compose exec nginx ls /
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of the base images are running in a alpine linux, that for space reasons do not have bash but sh, so try with

```
docker exec -ti <container> sh
```